# all column not display properly in the dynamic table of pdfMake in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdfmake

I made a dynamic table in pdf make. Everything works fine, data comes from the backend and is integrated in the pdf make, but when I downloaded the PDF, some of the columns is missing and some of the column data were showing partially. Let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
var dd = {
    content: [
        {
            style: 'tableExample',
            table: {
                body: [
                    ['ID', 'Name', 'Amount', 'Arrival', 'Checkout', 'TotalTime','phoneNumber','extendedTime']
                ]
            }
        },

    ],
    

}

export const BookingPDFData = (data) => {

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let values = Object.values(data[i]);
        dd.content[1].table.body.push(values);
    }

    return dd

}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the widths attribute in the table? Also, could you post a better image of your issue? The image you uploaded is zoomed in at 168% and we cannot see the right side of the page. It is hard to understand which columns aren't showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be it is due to the size of your content. Size of your content is bigger to fit in portrait, if you will change the pageOrientation to landscape then it may be fit in the page. You can do it as follow:

```
  pageSize: 'A4',
  pageOrientation: 'landscape',
```

If this is not the case then try to adjust fontsize of your columns.